# character array assignment error in C

Tags: c, error-handling

I have some code that is meant to read the first 3 characters from a character array that is read from a file, it was working then without changing anything is stopped working.
The 'command' char array use to hold "and" but now often holds "add▒" and sometimes "and0" but I've only declared it to be 3 long yet it still manages to hold more. Is there some context I am missing?

//ORIGINALLY THIS WORKED

```
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        command[i] = line[i];
    }

    /*Interpret AND or ADD or JMP */
    if (strcmp(command,"and") == 0){
        hexLine[0] = changeHex(5);
    }else if (strcmp(command,"add") == 0){
            hexLine[0] = changeHex(1);
    }else if (strcmp(command,"jmp") == 0){
            hexLine[0] = changeHex(12);
    }
    printf("%s", command);
```

//AND NOW THIS DOESNT WORK

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    command[i] = line[i];
}

/*Interpret AND or ADD or JMP */

if (strcmp(command,"and") == 0){
    hexLine[0] = changeHex(5);
}else if (strcmp(command,"add") == 0){
    hexLine[0] = changeHex(1);
}else if (strcmp(command,"jmp") == 0){
    hexLine[0] = changeHex(12);
}else if (strcmp(command,"ld ") == 0){
    hexLine[0] = changeHex(2);
}
printf("%s", command);
```

Comment: What exactly makes you think there's a fourth character in `command`?

Comment: I printf("%s", command);

Comment: Your `for` loop copies 3 characters but doesn't zero-terminate `command`. So `strcmp` won't behave the way you want. Put `command[i] = 0;` after your `for` loop.

Comment: Don't forget the null-character. See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/

Comment: i declared it as char command[4] and it know holds          <add▒GC=E▒@>
<and▒GC=E▒@>
<jmp▒GC=E▒@>
<ld ▒GC=E▒@>
<ld ▒GC=E▒@>
<add▒GC=E▒@>
<and▒GC=E▒@>

Comment: i would like to reitterate that this worked perfectly in for the last 3 versions but after adding stuff that didnt edit this part of the code it stopped working

Comment: If your question has been answered, please don't edit your question to reflect that fact. Instead *accept* the answer you think is correct.

Comment: sorry i am new to this

Comment: The main problem is changing other code changed the location on the stack, where the command array is located.  that resulted in the next char in the stack not being a '\0'  That is the symptom of the problem the actual problem is you do not have actual strings,, just an array of three characters.  therefore, ALL the strcmp(command, "...") need to be changed to strncmp(command, "...", 3) so only three chars are looked at.

Comment: BTW: a printf( "%s", command) will not normally work because it is expecting a null terminated string.  Instead use: printf( "%c%c%c", command)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `for` loop copies 3 characters but doesn't zero-terminate `command`. So `strcmp` won't behave the way you want. Put `command[i] = 0;` after your `for` loop.

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    command[i] = line[i];
}

command[i] = `\0';
```

As @Klaus points out in his comment: the above `for` loop assumes that you always have 3 valid characters to copy over. And, of course, `command` must be an array of at least 4 characters.

Comment: Thank you so much, this fixed the error even with only 3 spaces.

Comment: stepping on a 4th entry in command when command is only defined as three chars will corrupt the stack.  If you going to use this method, expand the size of command to 4 chars (still only read 3 chars.)

Comment: @user3629249 of course. Op's originsl code doesn't show the declaration of `command` but I have edited to make that clear in my response.

Comment: Generally, you should modify the code to accommodate the data rather than hacking data representation to accommodate the code.

Comment: @user3629249 indeed. But given that there is little information available for the OP's context, it's unclear whether the data is actually being "hacked" in this case.

Answer (score 0):

you need to put terminator character \0 in the end of the command char array

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
command[i] = line[i];
}

command[i + 1] = '\0';
```